# Designing a data flow for an advanced product search

Tags: search, product

I am on a very tight deadline project and I have been asked to deliver a data flow for an advanced product search. What's the best format I can deliver it so it can be understood by the client and the developers alike?

Comment: Have you asked your developer for examples of what they are looking for? This exercise tends to fall into the hands of an experienced information architect with some technical or library science background, in conjunction with a developer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can by opinion based.

It depends on the background of your developers and client. I'd suggest you try InVision, Axure, Scetch.